# Tkinter filename float not incrementing correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that loads the next file numerically upon the press of a button. In order to check what the next file is I simply run a while loop checking for a file name in .1 increments. I.E, I have a file labeled 1.1, 1.3, and 1.4, I want the button to load them in that order, skipping 1.2 because it doesn't exist.

The problem arising is that for some reason instead of just incrementing the value that gets checked by .1, it is incrementing it by .10000000000(some random number here), making it so I can't check the files properly

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

mainscreen = tk.Tk()

cuename = tk.Entry(mainscreen)


def loadnext_cue():
    cued = float(cuename.get())
    next_cue = cued + .1
    while os.path.exists("%s .txt" % str(next_cue)) == False:
        print(next_cue)
        next_cue += 0.1
        if next_cue >= 4:
            error = Label(mainscreen, text="No Higher Cue")
            error.pack(side=TOP)
            time.sleep(2)
            error.destroy()
            break
    if os.path.exists("%s .txt" % str(next_cue)):
        callup = next_cue
    
        with open("%s.txt" % str(callup), "r") as loadentry:
            quote = loadentry.read()
        T.delete("1.0", END)
        T.insert(END, quote)
```

Because of what I'm using the program for I know for now at least the file names will only go into the 10's place decimal (I.E. 1.2)

So, starting with file number 1.0, looking for the next file up, the output I'm getting looks something like this:

```
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
1.6000000000000005
1.7000000000000006
1.8000000000000007
1.9000000000000008
2.000000000000001
2.100000000000001
2.200000000000001
2.300000000000001
2.4000000000000012
2.5000000000000013
2.6000000000000014
2.7000000000000015
2.8000000000000016
2.9000000000000017
3.0000000000000018
3.100000000000002
3.200000000000002
3.300000000000002
3.400000000000002
3.500000000000002
3.6000000000000023
3.7000000000000024
3.8000000000000025
3.9000000000000026
4.000000000000003
```

It seems to go up by exactly .1 on the first iteration but then does whatever it wants after that. Any and all help would be appreciated

Comment: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) (python documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be due to the fact that they're floating point numbers. For example,

```
>>print(0.3+0.6)
0.8999999999
```

It prints 0.89999999 instead of 0.9. In your case,

```
num = 1
for _ in range(30):
    num+=0.1
    print(num)
```

Prints the output that you are getting. Instead what you could do is round them to the tens place so that you gen the answer you are looking for.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

mainscreen = tk.Tk()

cuename = tk.Entry(mainscreen)


def loadnext_cue():
    cued = float(cuename.get())
    next_cue = cued + .1
    while os.path.exists("%s .txt" % str(next_cue)) == False:
        print(next_cue)
        next_cue += 0.1
        next_cue = round(next_cue, 1) # rounds it to the tenths place
        if next_cue >= 4:
            error = Label(mainscreen, text="No Higher Cue")
            error.pack(side=TOP)
            time.sleep(2)
            error.destroy()
            break
    if os.path.exists("%s .txt" % str(next_cue)):
        callup = next_cue
    
        with open("%s.txt" % str(callup), "r") as loadentry:
            quote = loadentry.read()
        T.delete("1.0", END)
        T.insert(END, quote)
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully, thanks! Still not entirely sure why it doesn't give me the correct decimal automatically, but this solved it!

Comment: Check out the link posted by Bryan Oakley (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Hopefully that helps explain why it doesn't give the correct decimal automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your filenames are of the form x.y where x and y are both integers, but you are using a Python float to store the filename. Floats in Python represent decimal numbers with finite precision, and when you perform arithmetic you can experience a loss of precision. That is why when you perform 1.1 + 0.1 you get a very small error in the result -- the 'random number'.

I suggest to modify your code to store the parts x and y in separate variables as integers. You can increment the parts separately according to your logic, and then compose them into the string filename when needed.